# WebSphere Traditional Docker root access inside container

Tags: docker, websphere-8

I'm using WebSphere Traditional Docker It is using JDK 6 or 8 . I wonder How can I install JDK 7 on it ? I did not find installation manager command in container. I also tried to install JDK7 on container but it seems that I do not have permission to run bin file.

Answer (score 0):

Installation manager is used in the creation of the image but not packaged in the image itself in order to reduce the size of the image. If you want a different level of Java I would suggest re-building the image and changing the java level in the versions.csv file found here: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional/blob/master/developer/versions.csv

The above mentioned file is what is used by the build to pull down the required binaries for WebSphere Traditional and the required IBM Java.